# Не переходит на указанную ссылку при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, html, jsp

Есть такая кнопка                                 `<button class="btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Отменить фильтр" onclick="location.href = 'TmisqlController?action=list&page=1'" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>`
Она должна переходить по указанной ссылке, но почему-то при нажатии остается текущая страница `http://localhost:8080/ViewDb/SearchTmi?osdch=&nc=+21&svi=02.04.2018&page=1&count=0`
Кто знает в чем проблема.

Comment: Работало так `<input id="searchClear" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button" value="Відмінити фільтр" onclick="window.location.href = 'TmpsqlChController?action=list&page=1'" />` но не получается туда глификон поцепить вместо названия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Bootstrap добавляет свой onclick взамен этого. Он достаточно убогий, да и не претендует ни на что путное и полноценное.

2 решения:

1) Обернуть в "a href".

2) Обработчик клика добавлять динамически - addEventListener.

Comment: а как там можно в `a href` обернуть внутри тега? можете пример показать?

Comment: Если имелось ввиду так: `<a href="TmisqlController?action=list&page=1"><button class="btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Отменить фильтр"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></a>` то эффект тот же

Comment: как я понял проблема была в том что на в форме было две кнопки и вторая срабатывала как первая, вынес кнопку за форму и начало работать